# Can I make a browser session publicly accessible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, webrtc, tunneling

Is it possible to use something like a WebRTC ICE or STUN server to find an address for a browser session, so that anyone who has the address can access it?

1. U1's browser logs on to example.com
2. U1's browser session pings ICE/STUN/??? server to get a public address
3. U1's browser session address is published to example.com
4. U2 gets U1's address from example.com
5. U2 accesses U1's browser session either through a browser, or cURL/etc

Or to put it another way: Could I run a node-like server from within a browser, and make it publicly available?

I'm not asking for the legwork here, I just want to know if it's possible before I waste too much time.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @JonathanGray, I would be curious to how? With webrtc it is not possible to do this without doing a peerconnection due to the media being encrypted. I also do not believe you can share front end blobs this way because there is no existing media transport protocol in place(TCP stream or RTP).

Comment: I'm not sure how it would work in your specific situation but if I understand correctly you're basically talking about purposeful session hijacking. It all depends on your server's implementation. I don't have any experience with WebRTC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, check out [+PeerServer](http://www.peer-server.com/). It uses WebRTC's data channels, which is arguably a more elegant approach for step #5 in your question.